# spring MVC change displayed URL in controller

Tags: spring-mvc

I have an issue, let me introdues it:
I have a form which registers new users, the form then send information an address: ".../add-user.htm". In controller i have mapping for the address like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "add-user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView;
        List<String> errors = userService.userRegisterErrors(user);
        if(errors.size() == 0) {
            //some code here...
            modelAndView = new ModelAndView("index");

            List<String> info = new ArrayList<String>();
            info.add("Registration has been successful");
            info.add("Verification e-mail has been sent to Your e-mail address");
            modelAndView.addObject("info", info);
        } else {
            //some code here..
            modelAndView = new ModelAndView("user/register");
            modelAndView.addObject("user", user);
            modelAndView.addObject("errors", errors);
        }
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

At index page I'd like to show the info/error messages depends on if the registration was successful or not.
Let's assume the registration was correct for example. Then I'd like to see the index page with information for registration which works fine. The problem is with URL displayed at index page - it's not /index.htm as I wish, but it's /add-user.htm like controller defines. That's wrong because if i press "f5" button then it forces me to "re-register" the user.
I tried to use this method before returning modelAndView: `modelAndView.setViewName("index.htm");` but nothing happened. I can redirect to index page in controller, but then I would lost all objects in modelAndView so no information would not be displayed. Another idea I had was to use a flag for info and error but it would be very complicated. Do you have a solution? thanks.

Comment: Could [RedirectAttributes](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html) suit your needs? Available since 3.1.

Comment: Hmm so it does not suits me needs. I thought it can transfer objects but it's only for string, I need to transfer List and my own class, is it possible to do that?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html#addFlashAttribute-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object- seems to take an object as a value, i.e. not only strings. Why do you think it's only for strings?

Comment: I tried to use addObject, and it throwed exception that cannot convert myOwnClass to String.

Comment: But flash attributes are what I was looking for, it behaves like an object in ModeAndView, so addAttribute() is like for GET method-it has to be passed throught URL - it has to be String, but addFlashAttribute() is like POST- and you can pass whatever throught it, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you used RedirectAttributes from package `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support`? Because it does not seem to provide an `addObject` method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RedirectAttributes](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html) could suit your needs, especially the method [addFlashAttribute](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html#addFlashAttribute-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-). See the class' javadoc, it explains the purpose of using these attributes.